# Disabling Bootstrap on specific tags

Tags: css, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming

I've a Wordpress theme where I added bootstrap to use it's button UI and other things like progressBar and so on.
The issue is that Bootstrap affected the way the wordpress menu is rendered. 
I want to disable Bootstrap for the menu to disable this issue and have the default behaviour of the theme for the menu, but I want to keep the buttons, progressbar and the other things I'm using about Bootstrap.
Any suggestions to fix this?

Here some code that could be useful, I hope:

Menu declaration:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
```

This is how I added Bootstrap to the theme, inside functions.php:

```
 wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.0.1', true );
 wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.0.1', 'all' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
```

Comment: One suggestion would be to post your related code so we could get a better understanding of whats going on.

Comment: I didn't post any code because I don't know which bit could be useful to show. The wordpress menu structure is an UL tree that gets rendered with boostrap instead of the theme.

Comment: I'm thinking that the class names for your WP theme are conflicting with some of the class name from bootstrap. It would help to see the output of your menu code.

Comment: I think, there is only one way to solve the problem. You should use your special class for menu ````nav-menu```` to rewrite styles from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about how WordPress works, but have you considered customizing your Bootstrap build in order to only include what you actually want?

Head to the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and then just uncheck everything you don't want and just keep the bits you want, such as the buttons and progress bars. You will then get a much smaller version of the Bootstrap CSS and JS which only contains the components you want, which should hopefully fix your problem to a degree.